# Cakephp - displaying data using 'foreach' does not return any values

Tags: php, database, cakephp, foreach

I am trying to digest one of cakephp tutorials and yesterday I stuck. The sample website is called Jobfinds, so I have table name "jobs".

Here is the code from JobsController :

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Controller\AppController;

    class JobsController extends AppController{


    public $name = 'Jobs';

    /*
     * Default Index Method
     */

public function index() {
    //Set Query Options
    $options = array(
        'order' => array('Jobs.created' => 'asc' ),
        'limit' => 4
    ); 

    //Get Job Info

    $jobs = $this->Jobs->find('all', $options);

    $this->set('jobs', $jobs);
  }
}
?>
```

This code is in index.ctp but it doesn't show anything but it should.

```
<?php foreach($jobs as $job) : ?>
<p><?php  echo $job['jobs']['title'];
 ?> </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I put for example

```
<?php echo "something"; ?>
```

Then 'something' is being displayed so I figured that there must be just a small mistake that is does not fetch data from the table. I was trying for too long. I'm starting loosing my hair because of that. This tutorial is pretty awesome but there is used cakephp 2.x and I am using 3.x. so on every step I need to change something and up till now I succeeded but I stuck with this for good. Anyone can see where is the culprit? Why it doesn't fetch data from the table?

I have no errors in debug LOGS.

print_r($job) inside loop gives as below

```
    Cake\ORM\Entity Object ( [id] => 1 [category_id] => 7 [user_id] => 1          [type_id] => 1 [company_name] => Tech Guy Computer Services [title] => Senior Graphic Designer [description] =>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet(more description in lorem ipsum

[city] => Burlington [state] => MA [contact_email] => contact@employer.com [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object ( [time] => 2014-07-14T00:00:00+00:00 [timezone] => UTC [fixedNowTime] => ) [[new]] => [[accessible]] => Array ( [*] => 1 ) [[dirty]] => Array ( ) [[original]] => Array ( ) [[virtual]] => Array ( ) [[errors]] => Array ( ) [[invalid]] => Array ( ) [[repository]] => Jobs )
Cake\ORM\Entity Object ( [id] => 2 [category_id] => 7 [user_id] => 1 [type_id] => 1 [company_name] => Tech Guy Computer Services [title] => UX Designer [description] =>
```

Comment: see what print_r($job) is giving inside loop

Comment: I edited my post and pasted the result of print_r($jobs) at the bottom

Comment: try echo $job->title;   and read cakephp 3 documentation

Comment: Thanks Salines - echo $job->title; works great. I just figured that echo $job['title']; works as well.  I was looking blindly in documentation but just needed simple answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it's will help you.

```
<?php foreach($jobs as $job) : ?>
 <p><?php  echo $job['title'];?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I now see that I didn't need the ['Job'] before ['title']. I wonder why I haven't figured that out few hours erlier.

Comment: Thanks you. If answer is correct means, you will tick the answer. Hope its will help to others.

Comment: I ticked the comment up but I'm kinda new here below 15 points so it has been recorded but not showing yet.

Answer (score 0):

In `foreach($jobs as $job)`, here `$job` is entity object not a simple array. You can retrieve value of title by `$job->title`. Your code should be

```
<?php foreach($jobs as $job) : ?>
 <p><?php  echo $job->title;?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePhp 3 is totally based on ORM. Object Relational Mapping.

So you can access it using `$job->title;`

Also note that it will not give the actual model name as well. If you want to get the array then at the end of your query in controller you can use

`$jobs = $this->Jobs->find('all', $options)->toArray();`

Indeed you should use
    `$jobs = $this->Jobs->find()->limit(4)->order(array('Jobs.created' => 'asc' ))->toArray();`